# How to embed rollup bundle js content in HTML

Tags: javascript, rollup

I am using rollup to bundle a simple javascript application using `iife` format. But I wanted to embed the bundled javascript content inside an HTML file and couldn't find the right plugin to do that.

I am not looking for ways of embedding a script tag which **points to** the bundle javascript file ... but rather ways of embedding the bundle **content** inside an html file.

**Not looking for:** (which is possible using plugins)

```html
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

**Looking for:**

```html
<script>
    // actual bundle content (JavaScript code) here
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I wasn't able to find any solution, I forked the `rollup-plugin-generate-html-template` plugin and added the feature. Setting `embedContent: true` in the plugin options will suffice.

- The original plugin repository: [here](https://github.com/bengsfort/rollup-plugin-generate-html-template)
- My fork: [here](https://github.com/lgirma/rollup-plugin-generate-html-template)